# How to collapse (fold) Doxygen comments by default in vim?

Tags: c++, vim

We're looking at adding Doxygen documentation to C++ header files, but some people would prefer not to see the verbose Doxygen documentation by default.

Is there a way in .vimrc to fold (collapse) Doxygen comments by default?

Note: I have tried `autocmd FileType c,cpp set foldmethod=syntax` which will collapse all matching syntax, but I have been unable to figure out how to avoid collapsing functions, classes, et al., i.e. to only collapse Doxygen documentation format.

Another solution that looks like it might be a good one if the C-fold plugin for vim. Here's a detailed install sequence to get it working:

1. Add Doxygen syntax highlighting

(a) Install it from http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=5 which will create `~/.vim/syntax/doxygen.vim`.

(b) Add `~/.vim\ftdetect\doxygen.vim` with this single line:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.doxygen setfiletype doxygen
```

(c) Add `~/.vim/syntax/doxygen_load.vim` with these two lines:

```
au! Syntax {cpp,c,idl}
au Syntax {cpp,c,idl} runtime syntax/doxygen.vim
```

1. Add at the end of `~/.vimrc`:

   let mysyntaxfile='/home/dchinner/.vim/syntax/doxygen_load.vim'
   autocmd FileType c,cpp      set foldmethod=syntax
   autocmd FileType c,cpp      set foldlevel=10

Note that foldlevel determines how much will be folded initially. A high value will ensure most is open.

1. Add C-fold to (un)fold code or comments

(a) Install it from http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=1145 which will install `~/.vim/plugins/cfold.vim` and `~/.vim/after/syntax/c.vim`.

(b) Add at the end of `~/.vim/syntax/doxygen.vim`:

```
syn region doxygenComment start= ... keepend fold
```

Done! You can now use these C-fold plugin key-combos:

- `z[` opens all doxygen-style comments
- `z]` closes all doxygen-style comments
- `z{` opens all code blocks
- `z}` closes all code blocks

vim a file with Doxygen comments, and hit `z]` to fold the Doxygen comments.

Answer (score 2):

Both `syntax/c.vim` and `syntax/doxygen.vim` use syntax folding. Since there is no condition around the fold definitions in `c.vim`, you cannot turn off just one part.

You have to fork the default `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/c.vim` into `~/.vim/syntax/c.vim`, and remove all `fold` attributes from the syntax commands. That should leave just the doxygen parts folded (with `:set foldmethod=syntax`). The downside is that you have to maintain your special version of `c.vim` from now on.

Comment: Having to maintain a separate c.vim file will be somewhat difficult. Still looking for a solution that is easier to maintain.